# java.sql.SQLException: Problems with loading native library/missing methods: no ttJdbc181 in java.library.path

Tags: java, oracle, timesten

I am running TimesTen facing application in local (in eclipse IDE). URL and username and password seems to be fine. But I am getting below exception.

```
java.sql.SQLException: Problems with loading native library/missing methods: no ttJdbc181 in java.library.path
    at com.timesten.jdbc.JdbcOdbcConnection.connect(JdbcOdbcConnection.java:2012)
    at com.timesten.jdbc.TimesTenDriver.connect(TimesTenDriver.java:296)
    at com.timesten.jdbc.TimesTenDriver.connect(TimesTenDriver.java:152)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PooledConnection.connectUsingDriver(PooledConnection.java:319)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PooledConnection.connect(PooledConnection.java:212)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.createConnection(ConnectionPool.java:736)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.borrowConnection(ConnectionPool.java:668)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.init(ConnectionPool.java:483)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.<init>(ConnectionPool.java:154)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceProxy.pCreatePool(DataSourceProxy.java:118)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceProxy.createPool(DataSourceProxy.java:107)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceProxy.getPool(DataSourceProxy.java:214)
```

I checked the bin folder of TimsTen installation directory  did not see ttJdbc181.dll file Instead I found ttJdbcCS.181 in the folder. I don't know why code is looking for ttjdbc181.dll file.  I have tried adding  ttjdbc8,9,10,11  to class path still same issue. Any help to resolve this issue will be appreciated.

Comment: Can Someone help here?

Answer (score 2):

Had same stack trace.
All I had to do is to add "jdbc:timesten:client:" to my connection string. It is driver and protocol as far as my understanding goes.

My connection string looks like follows:

```
jdbc:timesten:client:TTC_Server=127.0.0.1;TTC_Server_DSN=myDsn;UID=user;PWD=userpasswd;TCP_PORT=9999;
```

This was issue on Windows. Assume same would arise for Linux.

Also please ensure you have correct CLASSPATH, Lib, Include, Path environment variables.
Windows installer usually takes care of this. On Linux you have to run ttenv.sh script from directory of your installed instance, this will set env vars as required.